# Message "the term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Tags: node.js, angular, powershell, npm, angular-cli

Today, while working through some basic AngularJS introduction, I ran into a problem.

I opened PowerShell to get going on the project. NPM worked.

I was able to install Angular using:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Anytime I tried to run *ng*, I would get:

> the term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: do it in "**Run as Administrator**" mode

Comment: I tried everything here to no avail. I also had to run `npm install -g @angular/cli` and then it worked.

Comment: Is it really AngularJS you are using? In 2017 you probably used Angular (without JS).

Answer (score 218, accepted):

The first path in the path variable needs to be the NPM path. Opening the Node.js command prompt I found that the ng command worked there. I dug into the shortcut and found that it references a command to ensure the first Path variable is NPM. 
To Fix:

1. Right Clicked on My Computer (windows)
2. Selected Advanced System Settings
3. Clicked "Environment Variables"
4. Under "Path" variable, made the FIRST value listed `%AppData%\npm`

Once I did that I was able to close powershell and reopen and all worked.

Comment: After following above steps "ng -v" working but "ng build" not working. It is giving this error "You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error."

Comment: You can also skip all of this in many cases by just typing "npm run ng...." Npm still usually works in powershell without alteration and 'npm run' will allow you to use ng commands.

Comment: It worked for me . I just want to understand why we are getting tis error after installing nodejs which is already in path.

Comment: very first you have to run powershell command 
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
second we have to run ng.ps1 using powershell ISE

Comment: I did this and now I am pass the not a cmdlet or function error.  But now I get, "ng cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.

Comment: @Sam that's not specific to the Angular CLI, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/64633727/3001761 (or the comment above yours, by the look of it).

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes I had to run SetExecutionpolicy RemoteSigned

Comment: This saved my life.  Last time setting 'Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned' worked for me.  This time it did not.  Setting the path worked this time.

Answer (score 212):

First set up Node.js, and then run this command to install Angular globally:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Now run the *ng* command. This worked for me.

Comment: this is certainly the correct answer if angular/cli not installed

Comment: THIS is what worked for me, the accepted answer made no difference at all.

Comment: I had to install a new environment and got the same issue. I have stumbled upon this answers, only to find out that I have already upvoted it. So since I can't upvote again, here's this comment for you. Thanks again Sir!

Answer (score 64):

I used the following:

```
npm run ng serve
```

It worked for me without need to set environment variables.

I had to install the TypeScript package after it:

```
npm install typescript@">=3.4 <3.6"
```

Comment: exactly what i wanted. it worked for me after running npm run ng serve

Comment: Yes, @Arun Surawat is correct, Just prefix npm run "original ng command"

Answer (score 33):

In the "Environment Variables"

In the "System variables" section

In the "Path" variable and before `"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"` add => `"%AppData%\npm"`

Comment: Exactly what needed.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Worked for me.Thank you. Had `.npmrc` file with `prefix` set as AppData path .

Comment: this worked for me although npm ng works by default after setting the path variables you dont' need to write npm.

Answer (score 26):

This solution worked for me:

*Add a path to your environment Variable*

```
C:\Users\YourPcName\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

As well as your bin folder of the Angular file (present their itself):

```
C:\Users\YoutPcName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin
```

And then run

```
ng -v
```

It will pop up the Angular CLI GUI in your Command prompt.

Note after running `npm i -g @angular/cli`, do restart your command prompt and check if it works. Otherwise, clean the cache and repeat the above steps.

Comment: After executing "ng install -g @angular/cli", I should have to set the AppData at path variable. Thanks, now I can work smoothly.

Comment: Works for me, close and restarted VSCode

Comment: I ran into similar issue with eas-cli in expo and I did exactly what you said for my own cli and it worked .I really  thank you , after a long search your  solution saved me

Answer (score 18):

Changing the policy to *Unrestricted* worked for me:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

Comment: Thanks... This is what I prefer above all the solutions given in this query. As all the solutions have their own consequences

Comment: Lowering the shields may not be the right course of action. What are the security implications?

Answer (score 14):

Installing Angular CLI globally solved my problem.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 13):

If you do not have access to environment variables (e.g., office machines), you can try to run a command like this:

```
npm run <your Angular command>
```

It works as well. You just need to add **npm run** before ***ng command***.

Example:

```
npm run ng g c shop/cart
```

[image]

Comment: That will cause ng create component not inside the current folder but in the root folder

Comment: It works for me, thanks.

Comment: I had to scroll so much to find this simple solution. Thanks

Comment: @efirat true but you can prefix with the desired path as shown in the answer given

Answer (score 10):

In Powershell, just add npx before ng and it will work:

```
npx ng serve
```

npx comes with npm since version 5.2

Comment: This is a good work-around if you are working in a place like a large financial institution where your machine is completely locked down and you don't have permissions to modify sys environment variables.

Answer (score 6):

#### For the Visual Studio Code Terminal

First open `cmd` and install `angular-cli` as global

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Then update your environment variables following these steps:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. This will open a search box
2. Type *Edit Environment Variables*
3. Open *Environment Variables*
4. Add `%AppData%\npm` inside `PATH`
5. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Close</kbd>.

Now you can restart your Visual Studio Code and it will work as it will normally do.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting this error in Visual Studio Code while doing `ng-build`. Running the below command in [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) fixed my issue:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 5):

Step 1 : Make sure the NodeJs version is udated to the recommended one. We can verify the version using

```
node -v
```

Step 2 : Uninstall Angular

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

Step 3 : Install Angular

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Step 4 : Verify Angular version

```
ng version
```

OR

```
ng v
```

Answer (score 4):

If your project name contains '-', remove it and try.

This can cause problems in running 'ng'.

Answer (score 4):

Open *Edit the system environment variables*.

In the "Path" and "PS Module Path" variable, add "%AppData%\npm"

Run Visual Studio Code as Administrator.

It works for me!

Comment: Re *"Run Visual Studio Code as Administrator"*: What are the security implications?

Answer (score 4):

**Selected Advanced System Settings**

[image]

**Clicked "Environment Variables"**

[image]

Under "Path" variable, made the *first* value listed to be **%AppData%\npm**

[image]

I did that. Close PowerShell and reopen. All worked.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to close Visual Studio Code and restart again. But to get the *ng* command to work in Visual Studio Code, you need to first compile the project with cmd in administrator mode.

I was also facing the same problem. But this method resolved it.

Comment: Re *"first compile the project with cmd in administrator mode"*: *Why* is that necessary? How does that work?

Answer (score 3):

I resolved it by following the below steps:

1. Right click on command prompt
2. Run as administrator
3. Type `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: you shouldn't install npm packages globally

Comment: @TarickWelling please provide a supporting argument for your statement.

Comment: Then why does -g exist? And how are you supposed to get CLI tools without -g?

Comment: Command prompt where? An already-opened PowerShell window? On already-opened CMD window? In the start menu somewhere? Inside Visual Studio Code? Something else?

Comment: @Jacob-JanMosselman that was probably a general (good) recommendation because it's the default approach for many junior devs no matter the package scope. For example, there are packages that are used only by the npm scripts defined in package.json (like checking for package licenses during the build), in which case there's no need to install them globally.

Answer (score 3):

1. I right-clicked on *My Computer* (Windows)
2. Selected Advanced System Settings
3. Clicked "Environment Variables"
4. Under "Path" variable, made the *first* value listed %AppData%\npm

**Initially**:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;

**After path adding**:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin;**%AppData%\npm;**%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;

**One more thing you can try, if the error is still coming, as below**

1. Go to project location via command prompt:C:\Users\brijeshray\ParentChild>
2. Reinstall or update existing angular as:

   ```
    npm install -g@angular/cli@latest
   ```
3. Go to computer or PC → *Properties* → *Advanced system setting* → *Environment Variable* → add a path below "User variable" (if 'Path' not there) → C:\Users\brijeshray\AppData\Roaming\npm → save it and restart Visual Studio Code

   [image]

Comment: What version of Windows?

Answer (score 3):

Fix: Running scripts is disabled on this system

Open PowerShell

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
A
```

(A: YES TO ALL)

Done!

Comment: Lowering the shields may not be the right course of action. What are the security implications?

Answer (score 3):

All answers are about how to fix it, but the best is to download Node.js and let the installer add to PATH variable.

Version 12 and 13 are too new, so I had to download [11.15](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v11.15.0/).

Answer (score 3):

to fix this error you need to follow these steps.

1. add the path of **%AppData%\npm** inside your environment variable click **Path** and put the path inside.
2. run your terminal as admin and use this command **npm install @angular/cli**
3. now you can run the following command **ng version**
4. and that all of you need to do. happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the "ng serve" command in the Visual Studio code terminal, open the Angular app path in the command prompt (*Run as Administrator*).

Then issue "ng serve" command.

Then open a browser and go to the *http://localhost:4200/*.

It works for me.

Comment: OK, PowerShell probably implies Windows (though it also runs on Linux).

Answer (score 2):

Also you can run the following command to resolve it:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also make sure you run the Command Prompt - or whatever terminal you use - As Administrator. I am using Visual Studio Code and the `ng serve` command gives me that exact error when not running Visual Studio Code as an administrator.

Comment: OK, PowerShell probably implies Windows (though it also runs on Linux).

Answer (score 1):

You should update Node.js to the latest version. Otherwise uninstall Node.js and install it again.

Answer (score 1):

This PowerShell script worked to add the correct setting to my environment variable "Path" (as a per-user setting). It adds: %AppData%\npm—and then restart the command line that uses "ng".

```
$existingPath = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "User")
Write-Host "existing PATH variable is $existingPath"
$newPath = "%AppData%\npm;$existingPath"
Write-Host "new      PATH will be     $newPath"

# Update here
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $newPath, "User")

$finalPath = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "User")
Write-Host "final    PATH variable is $finalPath"
```

Comment: Works as described.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is *not* the install of the NPM nor the path!

If you want to use the "ng" command, you need to install the angular-cli by running the following command

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

https://cli.angular.io/

Answer (score 1):

Exit everything and run `npm i -g @angular/cli` in a command prompt

And build your Angular application there itself (do not build on PowerShell).

Answer (score 1):

It is helped for me (for Windows):

1. Delete folders:

   ```
   C:\Users\**YourName**\AppData\Roaming\npm
   C:\Users\**YourName**\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
   ```
2. Install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/en/download/
3. In the terminal:

   ```
   npm install -g @angular/cli
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Lowering the shields may not be the right course of action. What are the security implications?

Answer (score 1):

vs code and native powershell

powershell > run in admin follow same steps

run in vs code admin

npm install -g @angular/cli

close vs code

run vs code not admin

ng will work

Answer (score 0):

I was using npm (5.5.1). Updating it to the latest version solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run PowerShell or command prompt *not* as administrator.

Comment: This seems to ***contradict*** other answers. What is the explanation? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55266327/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

After changing the path you have to restart PowerShell. You do not need to restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answers, here is the consolidation.

1. Run the command `npm install -g @angular/cli@project_version`
2. Add the below paths to your environment variables → *System Variables* → *Path* (for which administrator access is required).

   ```
   C:\Users\YourPcAccountName\AppData\Roaming\npm
   C:\Users\YoutPcAccountName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin
   ```

   Make sure the first value listed as `%AppData%\npm`
3. Reopen your command prompt from your project folder and run `ng serve`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the 'ng serve' command in the command prompt.
It compiled the project successfully. Then whatever changes are saved in Visual Studio Code, are automatically refreshed in the browser.

PS: I have installed Angular globally.

Answer (score 0):

Please also make sure that the [*node_modules* folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) also exists there in the project directory. If it is not there you will get a similar issue. So please run `npm install` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the correct answers have been given, all of these didn't work for me because:

- My username didn't have the **Administrator** privileges and I couldn't update the environment variable like suggested in the answers.

Here is what I did:

Instead of **`ng serve`**, I copy-pasted the complete location path of `ng` like the following and it worked.

So the `ng serve` command became:

```
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd serve
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Node.js is also an option. It will set the [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) variable automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Environment Variables"

In the "System variables" section

In the "Path" variable and before "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs" add => "%AppData%\npm"

And also do:

```
npm install
```

Then restart your Visual Studio Code. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without updating environment variables 
create new project:

```
npx @angular/cli@latest new project-name
```

now you can use ng commands inside that project

Answer (score 0):

Delete chocklatey -> u can find your chocklatey folder in `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey`  or check in system envirnment variables

1. then Re-install node.js
2. then open cmd in your project
3. then execute `ng add @angular/material`

Answer (score 0):

## Latest Solution

1 - First of all, you must run this command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

By default the `npm` install **`ng`** to the following path:
`C:\Users\pc-name\AppData\Roaming\npm` so you must add this path to the environment variable in path.

**Windows**-> **Environment Variable** -> **Path** -> add new Link then add : `C:\Users\pc-name\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Will be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

it is due to missing global path

npm config get prefix
//get global path

npm config set prefix "C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm"
//set appdata npm folder as global path

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli@latest
//uninstall old angular cli

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
//install latest angular cli

add this path in environment variable >>C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm
add this in system variable >>C:\Program Files\nodejs\

where ng
//check ng command install correctly or not, it will return ng.cmd file location.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
npm run build:prod
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31402110)

Answer (score -1):

Remove the @ng_module directory and run `ng init`. this command basically installs all the packages and modules required for the project.

ps: don't remove the package.json and angular.json from the project.

Comment: ng command is not recognized..how ng init will work!