# Visual Studio Code 2017 debug angular code

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio

I created project Angular + Nodejs with this tutorial: "https://youtu.be/DqtKuXFfhsQ". When I want to debug project in Visual Studio Code 2017 by "ng serve", Studio Code says me:

```
D:/ ... "SOME PATH"> ng serve
ng : The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable p
rogram. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
 and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ng serve
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ng:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

In PowerSheel works ng serve --open, but in Visual Studio Code is not working. What should I do to repair my problem? Thanks

Comment: Try to reinstall the Angular cli globally npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: Thake a look on this answer also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958847/the-term-ng-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet

Comment: Yes, it is work! I reinstalled Angular in powershell in my project by npm install -g @angular/cli and all work in Visual Studio Code. Thanks.