# Why are my Node packages and CLI commands not recognized?

Tags: node.js, npm, package, command-line-interface

I've run into this issue recently, which has never occured before, and I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be doing.

I tried running 'ng serve' to view my Angular project, but I got an error that looks something like this:

> ng : The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I searched this up online and found a solution, so I thought this was a one time thing. I tried running a different package just now (nodemon, in this case) and got the same error. It seems that the packages I need to run through the command line are not working. I haven't tried uninstalling Node just yet but I've tried reinstalling the packages, deleting the entire project folder and cloning from my Github repository, deleting node_modules...nothing so far.

Comment: What is your OS? Have you check your env and path for node? What pops up if you run `node --version` from console? Have you reinstalled angular cli globally? Can you execute `ng` from node command prompt? Have you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958847/the-term-ng-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet/44958882)

Comment: As for OS, I'm on Windows 10. Running `node --version` from the console returns the version and running `ng` from the node consoles appears to be working.

Comment: did you use `-g` when installing ng or nodemon? i.e. `npm i -g nodemon`