# How to fix "running scripts is disabled on this system"?

Tags: powershell

When I try to run ionic commands like `ionic serve` on the VS Code terminal, it gives the following error.

How can I fix this?

```
ionic : File C:\Users\Lakshan\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see 
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Answer (score 160, accepted):

I found a way to fix this error.

It is as follows:

1. First, **Open PowerShell** with **Run as Administrator**.
2. Then, run this command in PowerShell

   ```
   Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
   ```
3. After that type `Y` and press Enter.

Comment: The "Unrestricted" execution policy is generally considered risky. A better choice would be "Remote-Signed", which doesn't block scripts created and stored locally, but does prevent scripts downloaded from the internet from running unless you specifically check and unblock them.

Comment: Read more about Execution Policies (AllSigned, Bypass, Default, RemoteSigned, Restricted, Undefined, Unrestricted) 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.2
To remove the execution policy for a particular scope, set the execution policy to *Undefined*.

Comment: In powershell
# To check the current execution policy, use the following command:
Get-ExecutionPolicy

# To change the execution policy to Unrestricted, which allows running any script without digital signatures, use the following command:
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

# This solution worked for me, but be careful of the security risks involved.

Comment: There is no "Remote-Signed" (with a dash) option as of 2023...

Answer (score 11):

This is because of Execution Policy. This defines how powershell scripts will run.

In Default windows desktops, it is Restricted, not allowing any scripts (signed or unsigned) only interactive sessions.

So best is you set using `RemoteSigned` (Default on Windows Server) letting only signed scripts from remote and unsigned in local to run, but `Unrestriced` is insecure lettting all scripts to run.

To set run `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` as administrator.

Answer (score 9):

This code will fix it:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned –Scope Process
```

Comment: This is the most secure option, as it only affects the current session.

Comment: I tried this option and other options, but still getting the same error. I even tried Unrestricted, but no luck, here is the error: File C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MicrosoftTeams\5.5.0\MicrosoftTeams.psm1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.

Answer (score 5):

To Bypass this you need to change the Execution policy.
Type this into your terminal.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser
```

then it will prompt you to supply a value at which point you can set Bypass / RemoteSigned or Restricted.

```
cmdlet Set-ExecutionPolicy at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
ExecutionPolicy: "RemoteSigned" or "Bypass" or "Restricted".
```