# I am not able to install or run yarn start command in my vscode

Tags: reactjs

PS C:\Users\vinit\vinitkr\comeplete_react_2023\reactvinitapp> yarn start
yarn : File C:\Users\vinit\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.ps1
cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on
this system. For more information, see
about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- yarn start
- ~~

  - CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSec
    urityException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

what should
i do.??

i want to fix this so i can start it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "running scripts is disabled on this system"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64633727/how-to-fix-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)