# i can't run npm install in my laravel 10 project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, npm-install, vue-loader

[image]

I want to install vue in my Laravel project so I run this command

```
npm i vue-loader@next vue@next vue-router@next
```

but it gives me the same error in the image above and I try to do just npm I and it won't work i use laragon this project have node version: v-18.8,0

Comment: Try open a Powershell Terminal with 'Run as Admin' if that is working, run  your VS code as Admin next time you open it.

Comment: It's an issue with the computer's script execution policies, not the project.  If this is not your personal computer, you should bring it up with your work team or IT department.  If it is your personal computer, search your error online and you will find recommended [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64633727/how-to-fix-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Comment: @yoduh  thank you  i solved the problem by opening Powershell as admin and i ran those commands 
Get-ExecutionPolicy
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestrict
I follow this vedeo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8CPnfbiWTc