# Getting error System.Management.Automation.PSSecurityException HResult=0x80131501 in web application

Tags: c#, powershell, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

I created App Service in Azure Portal and Published my web application code to web App. In Web Application Powershell scripts not not executing and tried to attach debugger process to Web application and getting below error in exception.

Below is the error:

> System.Management.Automation.PSSecurityException
> HResult=0x80131501
> Message=File C:\home\site\wwwroot\Scripts\KeyVault.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170
> Source=System.Management.Automation
> StackTrace:
> at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
> at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline.Invoke()
> at MSaaSPartnerOnboarding.Repository.RolesRepository.CreateAADAPP(RolesModel roles) in D:\KVPowershell\Repository\RolesRepository.cs:line 32
>
> Inner Exception 1:
> UnauthorizedAccessException: File C:\home\site\wwwroot\Scripts\KeyVault.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.**

Below is my Powershell Script:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$KeyVaultName
)
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
Set-AzContext -Subscription "<<SubscriptionId>>"
New-AzKeyVault -VaultName $KeyVaultname -ResourceGroupName 'testrg' -Location 'East US'
```

Below is the C# code:

```
public void CreateKV(RolesModel roles)
{
    try
    {
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create();
        string scriptPath = @"./Scripts/KeyVault.ps1";          
        Command mycmd = new Command(scriptPath);
        Collection<CommandParameter> commandParameters = new Collection<CommandParameter>();
        commandParameters.Add(new CommandParameter("KeyVaultName", roles.KeyVaultName));

        foreach (CommandParameter commandParameter in commandParameters)
        {
            mycmd.Parameters.Add(commandParameter);
        }
        pipeline.Commands.Add(mycmd);
        pipeline.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("ErrorActionPreference", "Stop");
        Collection<PSObject> psObjects;
        psObjects = pipeline.Invoke();
        runspace.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Script is executing locally but when I try to execute in Web Application it is not working.

Comment: “_running scripts is disabled on this system_”

Comment: Is there any command to enable to run scripts on App Service?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64633727/how-to-fix-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system

Answer (score 1):

> Below is the error:

> System.Management.Automation.PSSecurityException HResult=0x80131501 Message=File C:\home\site\wwwroot\Scripts\KeyVault.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.

It is clearly mentioned in the error that ***"script cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system."*** So, this is related to the execution policy of the user scope and thanks to *@stuartd* for pointed out in the right direction.

Changing the execution policy to `RemoteSigned` should solve the issue. To do this, Open `PowerShell` as *"run as administrator"* and retrieve the execution policies enabled on the environment using `Get-ExecutionPolicy`  as shown below. If "remote signed" is not present, then set execution policy as remote signed.

**`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy  RemoteSigned`**

Reference [blog](https://tecadmin.net/powershell-running-scripts-is-disabled-system/) for the relevant issue.

I have checked in `App servcie >> Kudu console >> PowerShell` and was set to the expected policy values:-

[image]

Also check you have necessary permissions in the Azure Web App to run the PowerShell script. (Eg: Contributor role)

If still the issue persists, try setting the execution policy to unrestricted as shown below.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

***Note***: Allowing `unrestricted` access to PowerShell scripts is not recommended as it could lead to security conflicts, particularly if the data involved is confidential.