# Conda is not recognised?

Tags: c++, conda

**I am running a simple c++ code on Visual Studio and execution is also successful but this red thing appears . How to solve it ?**

**Text written in red in image is :-**

```
conda : the term 'conda'is not recognized as the name of cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:1
 
+ conda activate base 
+ ~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

[image]

Comment: Unreadable. Please avoid posting images, instead copy'n paste the text, using correct formatting.

Comment: Assuming you installed conda, you need edit your PATH environment variable such that the path to the executable is in one of the folders listed in the PATH. If it is already so then you may want to logout then login for this to activate.

Comment: this looks like output generated from the program you run. You need to read documentation of the library you are using or inspect your code to know where it comes from

Comment: Please paste the text.  I can't read that, and if I could, I can't copy/paste any of it.

Comment: This is just a case of not knowing how to use the command line / not understanding how the `PATH` environment variable is used by the OS to find the location of the executable. Here is some info on how to set this: [https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/)

Comment: @kebs I have edited the post . Kindly revisit it again.

Comment: Related if not a duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597662/conda-command-is-not-recognized-on-windows-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597662/conda-command-is-not-recognized-on-windows-10)

Comment: I have already told you the solution more than once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958847/the-term-ng-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet)

Comment: This is not answerable without any code. And what has Conda (which is Python-related) anything to do with C++?

Comment: You can use `conda` to install c++ libraries.