# Debug not working on CS50 practice problem

Tags: c, debugging, cs50

Trying to do CS50 week 1 practice problem "Debug'. I've followed it step by step repeatedly for hours and cant seem to get away from this error.

When I 'make' debug, I get an error saying

```
The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, 
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again..
```

I can run Debug on code.cs50.io, but I'm unable to run debug on the actual VS Code App on windows 11. I tried to copy paste the code itself into code.cs50.io but I get this error

```
make debug
debug50 ./debug

Can't debug this program! Are you sure you are running debug50 
on an executable, a Python script, or a Java program?
Unsupported File: ./debug
```

I am very new to VS Code and coding in general, so can someone please explain this to me ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I did cs50 but it was a couple of years ago. I can’t remember if I did it on windows or linux. Anyway, I think the clue here is:

> The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again..

If you have not installed make then you have to install it.

Try here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57042516/11112270

If you do have it installed, then the binary executable is not in $PATH env variable.

Try here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44958882/11112270

IMO, just develop on linux since it’s much easier to get tools you need. Unless cs50 requires windows?

Comment: any thoughts on how i may have lost the ability to make? everything was working fine, i followed along coding during the lecture videos, and as soon as i started the debug practice problem i've been unable to do anything that i could before