# Angular build conflicts

Tags: node.js, angular

I am setting up a new laptop. I have installed node.js application and trying to build my Angular project which works fine on the old laptop. Here are the errors:

```
pm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: aveva-web-analytics@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/cdk@11.2.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"^11.2.7" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/cdk@"^10.0.0-rc.0" from @angular/flex-layout@10.0.0-beta.32
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/flex-layout
npm ERR!   @angular/flex-layout@"^10.0.0-beta.32" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

what confuses me is how come it works on the other box?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the same version of Node, NPM and Angular?

Comment: Angular is the same, but Node is probably not. I installed whatever they have on their website. Latest LTS Version: 18.15.0 (includes npm 9.5.0)

Comment: I installed the same node version that works on the other box, still same errors

Answer (score 0):

`@angular/flex-layout` asks for Angular 10, when your own dependencies has Angular 11.

You will need to update `@angular/flex-layout` to a newer version (likely `11.0.0-beta.33`).

Comment: Do you mean in my package.json file?

Answer (score 0):

Just update @angular/flex-layout to the latest version by using these command

```
ng update @angular/flex-layout
```

Comment: But ng commands wouldn't run. ng : The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958847/message-the-term-ng-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet